# How to keep the same padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I keep box 1,2,3 the same size? Even if the text gets out of the box, that's fine, cause they will be larger.

```css
.this-p {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 2;
  border-radius: 0%;
  width: auto -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="four" class="wrapper style3 special">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="major">
      <h2>hora de abrir a carteira</h2>
      <p>bora espiar ao vivo? ;)</p>
    </header>
    <ul class="actions">
      <p class="this-p"> <br> <span class="this-span"> PLANO BÁSICO </br> </span> 15 minutos </br>
        Janela fechada </br>
        Persiana 3/4 fechada </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
      <p class="this-p"> <br> <span class="this-span"> PLANO NA MÉDIA </br> </span> 30 minutos </br>
        Janela meia fechada </br>
        Persiana 2/4 fechada </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
      <p class="this-p"> <br> <span class="this-span"> PLANO TOP </br> </span> 60 minutos </br>
        Janela totalmente aberta </br>
        Persiana aberta </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: 3 boxes]

ps: also, is there any way I can remove the clickable option on those boxes? I don't know if i have to find the parent or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want elements to have same width, you need to define it. Removing `coursor: pointer` removes 'clickable' pointer.

#### Key part

```
.this-p {
  width: 150px;
  ...
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
.this-p {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  line-height: 2;
  border-radius: 0%;
  width: auto -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section id="four" class="wrapper style3 special">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="major">
      <h2>hora de abrir a carteira</h2>
      <p>bora espiar ao vivo? ;)</p>
    </header>
    <ul class="actions">
      <p class="this-p"> <span class="this-span"> PLANO BÁSICO </br> </span> 15 minutos </br>
        Janela fechada </br>
        Persiana 3/4 fechada </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
      <p class="this-p"> <span class="this-span"> PLANO NA MÉDIA </br> </span> 30 minutos </br>
        Janela meia fechada </br>
        Persiana 2/4 fechada </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
      <p class="this-p"> <span class="this-span"> PLANO TOP </br> </span> 60 minutos </br>
        Janela totalmente aberta </br>
        Persiana aberta </br>
      </p>
      </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you! last thing, how can i center the text? looks this way: https://ibb.co/e6C0Gd - huge empty space below text

Comment: It's because `<br>` element at the beginning of content. I removed them and updated my snippet. If my answer answers your original question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: i removed <br> element and it went up more: https://ibb.co/iFMfhJ .. is it because its rounded?

Comment: Yes. Please place your code on some JSFriddle, so I can help you with that and create chat.